# how to filter out non-resource values in DBpedia SPARQL query?

Tags: rdf, sparql, semantic-web, dbpedia, linked-data

I have this query to return eras for philosophers that works:

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?philosopher ?era
WHERE {
   ?philosopher a  dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
       dbpprop:era ?era .
}
```

Example values of `?era` returned are:

- 19
- Modern Era
- http://dbpedia.org/resource/Contemporary_philosophy

I would like to return only eras that are resources.  I tried:

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?philosopher ?era
WHERE {
   ?philosopher a dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
                dbpprop:era ?era .
   ?era a <http://dbpedia.org/resource>
}
```

but this returns nothing. How can I filter out non-resource eras?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Rather than adding an additional triple pattern you actually want to use a `FILTER` with the `ISURI` function e.g.,

```
PREFIX dbpedia-owl: <http://dbpedia.org/ontology/>
PREFIX dbpprop: <http://dbpedia.org/property/>

SELECT ?philosopher ?era
WHERE {
   ?philosopher a dbpedia-owl:Philosopher ;
                dbpprop:era ?era .
   FILTER(ISURI(?era))
}
```

Comment: Perfect answer.  Here is a link to the documentation on isURI and related functions.  In this case it appears that all values are either URIs or Literals.                           http://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-isIRI